# Json Object cannot be cast to Float using parse.com cloud function Android

Tags: javascript, android, parse-platform, push-notification, cloud

I am following tutorial from https://parse.com/docs/cloud_code_guide?language=Android#functions-calling to get cloud data on android. Java Script code is given below:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("averageStars", function(request, response) {
  var query = new Parse.Query("Review");
  query.equalTo("movie", request.params.movie);
  query.find({
    success: function(results) {
      var sum = 0;
      for (var i = 0; i < results.length; ++i) {
        sum += results[i].get("stars");
      }
      response.success(sum / results.length);
    },
    error: function() {
      response.error("movie lookup failed");
    }
  });
});
```

The code at android side is given below:

```
 @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            // Get the view from listview_main.xml
            setContentView(R.layout.listview_main);
            HashMap<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            params.put("movie", "The Matrix");
            ParseCloud.callFunctionInBackground("averageStars", params, new FunctionCallback<Float>() {
              public void done(Float ratings, ParseException e) {
                   if (e == null) {
                      // ratings is 4.5
                   }
               }
            });
            // Execute RemoteDataTask AsyncTask
            new RemoteDataTask().execute();
        }
```

I have also successfully deployed code from parse console to cloud. But i am getting error: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.json.JSONObject$1 cannot be cast to java.lang.Float

Kindly acknowledged me where i am doing wrong. I have perfectly follow tutorial. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where do you get this exception. Anyway every object in Java has method toString(), try to use it

Comment: @MikeMinaev thank you for your reply. I have edited my post by mistake i wrote java.lang.String. Exactly the error is java.lang.ClassCastException: org.json.JSONObject$1 cannot be cast to java.lang.Float On debug it gives an error at this line  'ParseCloud.callFunctionInBackground("averageStars", params, new FunctionCallback<Float>() {'

Comment: @muhammadusmankhan i think the issue is in their SDK. If your CloudCode returns say 4.5, the your android function is like 'ParseCloud.callFunctionInBackground("averageStars", params, new FunctionCallback<Double>() {' then all works fine. However if your CloudCode returns 4, then it would crash. My workaround was to return String from CloudCode and in android code convert string to float.

Comment: FWIW, I got a very similar error when I was trying to return a `ParseObject` but was returning a `NULL` value. I wound up doing this to see if I had a valid result or not: `if (returnedObject.getClass() != ParseObject.class) {`. Not sure if the same thing applies to primitives.

Answer (score 0):

You are not override the done method of `FunctionCallback<Float>();`

Please replace the parse cloud function like this:

```
ParseCloud.callFunctionInBackground("averageStars", params, new FunctionCallback<Float>() {
    @Override
    public void done(Float ratings, ParseException e) {
        if (e == null) {
            // ratings is 4.
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason is there is no Review data.
results.length is 0
so `response.success(sum / results.length);` will be a `{}` null JSON object.
My solution is: check the devide by zero exception and always return String
`var avg = 0;
if (results.length != 0) avg = sum / results.length
response.success(avg.toString());`